# Resolve host to full url like curl in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns

If you type `google.com` in the browser address bar it will resolve to `https://www.google.com/`.

How would one take a partial URL and resolve it to a full URL in node in the same way the browser does?

I've tried using the node DNS module, which I can resolve google.com to an ip address but I can't seem to get all the way. Not even sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find https://github.com/jksolbakken/linkfollower, which does solve my problem. Sometimes, asking the question helps me find the solution.